# Proving independence of the neighborhood axioms in topology

Tags: general-topology, axioms

I have not found any information on this topic on StackExchange or through a few minutes of searching with Google.

This question is Exercise 8 in Section 2.1 on page 22 of *Topology and Groupoids*, by Brown. I am given the neighborhood axioms

> 1. If $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then $x \in N$.
> 2. If $N$ is a subset of $X$ containing a neighbourhood of $x$, then $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.
> 3. The intersection of two neighbourhoods of $x$ is again a neighbourhood of $x$.
> 4. Any neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains a neighbourhood $M$ of $x$ such that $N$ is a neighbourhood of each point of $M$.

and I am asked to prove that these four axioms are independent. It is my understanding that this can be accomplished by selecting selecting any subset of three axioms and supplying a purported neighborhood topology $\mathcal{N}$ that satisfies the all the axioms except the one that hasn't been selected. This requires $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ examples.

I think I have one example. If I say that $N$ is a neighborhood of $x \in X$ if and only if $N = \{ x \}$, then I think this satisfies axioms 1, 3 and 4 but not 2.

I haven't come up with any other examples yet, though. I looked briefly at *Counterexamples in Topology* by Steen and Seebach but it didn't look like they deal with this type of question.

Does anyone know of any other examples that will work? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I think I have another example. Let $X$ = $[0, 1]$ and say that $N$ is a neighborhood of $x \in X$ if and only if $\frac{1}{2} \in N$, then I think that satisfies axioms 2, 3 and 4 but not 1.

If I'm correct about both of these examples then I'm halfway to a solution.

Comment: Looks like you'll manage to answer on your own :). Example one doesn't work when your space contains only one point, try fixing it.

Comment: Example 2 is good

Comment: @FormulaWriter Can I fix the first example by picking an $X$ containing more than one point?

Comment: Yes, you can. if your space has more than one point, any subset $N$ for which $\{x\}$ is a proper subset doesn't satisfy 2. Good job!

Comment: Steen and Seebach deal with topological spaces, you want spaces that are *not* topological on purpose.. So they don't list such examples.

Comment: These axioms are satisfied by an empty neghborhood system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1) you can let $X$ be any infinite set, and for each $x\in X$ let

$$\mathscr{N}(x)=\{X\setminus F:F\text{ is a finite subset of }X\}\;;$$

I’ll leave it to you to verify that (2)-(4) are satisfied and (1) is not.

For (3) let $X=\{0,1,2\}$. Let $\mathscr{N}(0)=\big\{\{0,1\},X\big\}$, $\mathscr{N}(1)=\big\{\{0,1\},\{1,2\},X\big\}$, and $\mathscr{N}(2)=\big\{\{1,2\},X\big\}$.

For (4) you can again let $X=\{0,1,2\}$, but this time let $\mathscr{N}(0)=\big\{\{0,1\},X\big\}$, and $\mathscr{N}(1)=\mathscr{N}(2)=\big\{\{1,2\},X\big\}$.